# Boxes placement in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I'd like to know if there is a way to place tcolorboxes like this:

```
-------- --------
| box1 | |      |
-------- | box3 |  
-------- |      | 
| box2 | |      |
-------- --------
```

To do that I'm actually placing the boxes inside tikz nodes, but that seems like an overkill solution. Is there a tikz-free approach?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Obviously, you would use the `\tcbox` macro version for your boxes, rather than the environment form.  Calculation of the stackgap is shown automated in this MWE.  (Note:  this example works starting with V2.30 of tcolorbox).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\def\boxone{\tcbox[nobeforeafter]{This is a test}}
\def\boxtwo{\tcbox[nobeforeafter]{Another test}}
\def\boxthree{\tcbox[nobeforeafter,minipage,width=0.7in]{this is a very long box}}

\stackon[\heightof{\boxthree}-\heightof{\boxone}-\heightof{\boxtwo}]%
  {\boxtwo}{\boxone}~\boxthree

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this work with [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)?

Comment: Should work with `tcolorbox`; just remember to give the boxes a fixed width (and, maybe, height).

Comment: never heard of this package before, thanks. Anyway, is it possible to align the third box with the first, assuming that the third box height is not equal to the sum of the other two boxes? @Werner just tested, it works.

Comment: @werner I revised solution to demonstrate with `\tcbox`

Comment: @Lep The  `stackengine` package is new.  I just wrote it in recent weeks.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes here your new mwe does not produce the result shown in the picture: the second box goes behind the first

Comment: @Lep I don't understand your comment. about "second box goes behind the first".  Unless you are questioning the syntax of the `\stackon` command.  In that case, the first mandatory argument is the "anchor" of the stack.  So, you might read it as "stack on the anchor(box2), an item(box1)."  This syntax was used because the pacakge supports both overstacks and understacks.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm sorry for not being clear. I was just asking you to check your last MWE because when I compile it here I don't get the result you are showing in the picture, so maybe there is a typo or you have a different version of your package than mine?

Comment: [this](http://oi41.tinypic.com/344zdcl.jpg) is what I get from your MWE

Comment: I get the same image as @lep links to: something wrong after the edits?

Comment: @Lep  I have confirmed that I am using the version 1.0 of stackengine found at http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine.  I do not get the erroneous result you and Joseph Wright get.  The version of tcolorbox I have is V2.22, dated 2013/05/15.

Comment: @Lep I note that the tinypic you provide does not honor the `\\\` commands I have placed in my "long box" (I didn't know [without reading the tcolorbox docs] how else to make the box multiple lines). Perhaps you have an outdated tcolorbox version.

Comment: I have version 1.0 of your package and version 2.32 (2013/06/23) of tcolorbox. And with the new edit it still doesn't work as expected. Could you update to version 2.32 of tcolorbox and see if it is the "problematic" version? @JosephWright

Comment: @Lep Indeed, V2.32 of tcolorbox apparantly changes (and in my opinion) breaks the behavior.  Changing back and forth between 2.32 and 2.32 demonstrates it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Actually, `\tcbox` was buggy before 2.30 because it slurped the `before` and `after` code. After bug-fixing it has the expected behavior. That means, on the other hand, that you have to clear the `before` and `after` code if you want to use `\tcbox` like `\mbox`. I've edited your example and added `nobeforeafter` to do that. Otherwise, you could make a new box by `\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,#1}`. This `\mybox` behaves like the buggy old `\tcbox` and you have the bug as a feature :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm  Thanks for that intervention.

Answer (score 11):

Taking a similar tack to [Steven Segletes's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122285) but using the [`xcoffins`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcoffins) package, which allows us to pick points on the various boxes to line up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{xcoffins}
\NewCoffin{\CoffinA}
\NewCoffin{\CoffinB}
\NewCoffin{\CoffinC}
\begin{document}
% Set up content in three coffins
\SetHorizontalCoffin{\CoffinA}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width = 1 in]
    This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.%
  \end{tcolorbox}
}%
\SetHorizontalCoffin{\CoffinB}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width = 1 in]
    This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.%
  \end{tcolorbox}
}%
\SetHorizontalCoffin{\CoffinC}{\rule{1 in}{2.5 in}}%
% Join the first small coffin onto the big one at the top
\JoinCoffins{\CoffinC}[t,l]{\CoffinA}[t,r](-0.1 in, 0 in)%
% Join the second small coffin onto the big one at the bottom
\JoinCoffins{\CoffinC}[b,\CoffinC-l]{\CoffinB}[b,r](-0.1 in, 0 in)%
\TypesetCoffin{\CoffinC}

\end{document}
```

Here, I've added a small gap between the coffins (it's negative as I've done everything relative to the large item, `\CoffinC`.)

The 'coffin' system works by having 'handles' on the boxes it creates: we can address those by letters, *e.g.* `t` for 'top', and also refer to points on coffins we've already combined. This allows relatively easy construction of complex box relationships.

Comment: The package `xcoffin` is a great interface to `l3coffin`. Unfortunately it is very unpopular yet.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Maybe because it is in the _experimental_ branch?

Answer (score 1):

`tcbraster` is a `tcolorbox` library for distribution of boxes inside another box.

With a raster inside another raster is easy to obtain something similar to  desired distribution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

% External raster
\begin{tcbraster}[%
    raster width=.6\linewidth,
    raster columns=2, 
    % Forces same height in all columns on same row
    raster equal height=rows,
    raster every box/.style={valign=center, halign=center}, 
    ]
% Inner raster: left column boxes
\begin{tcboxedraster}[%
    raster columns=1, 
    raster width=\linewidth, %otherwise inherits `.6\linewidth`
    ]{blankest} %<- no drawn box or white space around inner boxes
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        This is a text
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[blankest, height=1cm]
        % This is a phantom box. It introduces a vertical gap
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        This is another text
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcboxedraster}
% <--- Important: No white space or break line between elements
% Box for right hand column.
\begin{tcolorbox}
    This is a very long long text
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]